# Odd Results on Multiple Slideshows

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I've been working on a page on which a number of images are to change into other images and while it kind of works, most of the slideshows seem to stop at the second image and just keep repeating that one. They do the fadeouts/fadeins as intended and change at different rates per the intended effect. But each slideshow is supposed to rotate between 3 and 5 images and most of these never appear at all. I'm new to CSS and am probably missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what. It's especially puzzling that some behave differently than others, since they're all coded in the same way. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the final product: https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/ 
Here is the code:

```js
var myimages = new Array()

function preloadimages() {
  for (i = 0; i < preloadimages.arguments.length; i++) {
    myimages[i] = new Image()
    myimages[i].src = preloadimages.arguments[i]
  }
}

preloadimages("couple1.jpg", "couple2.jpg", "couple3.jpg", "animated1.jpg", "animated2.jpg", "animated3.jpg", "cold1.jpg", "cold2.jpg", "cold3.jpg", "shock1.jpg", "shock2.jpg", "shock3.jpg", "art1.jpg", "art2.jpg", "art3.jpg", "art4.jpg", "art5.jpg", "colorful1.jpg", "colorful2.jpg", "colorful3.jpg", "group1.jpg", "group2.jpg", "group3.jpg", "epic1.jpg", "epic2.jpg", "epic3.jpg", "hero1.jpg", "hero2.jpg", "hero3.jpg", "hero4.jpg", "tough1.jpg", "tough2.jpg", "tough3.jpg", "tough4.jpg", "tough5.jpg")


var coupleIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("coupleSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  coupleIndex++;
  if (coupleIndex > x.length) {
    coupleIndex = 1
  }
  x[coupleIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
}

var animatedIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("animatedSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  animatedIndex++;
  if (animatedIndex > x.length) {
    animatedIndex = 1
  }
  x[animatedIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 8500);
}

var coldIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("coldSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  coldIndex++;
  if (coldIndex > x.length) {
    coldIndex = 1
  }
  x[coldIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 7000);
}

var shockIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("shockSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  shockIndex++;
  if (shockIndex > x.length) {
    shockIndex = 1
  }
  x[shockIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 5500);
}

var artIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("artSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  artIndex++;
  if (artIndex > x.length) {
    artIndex = 1
  }
  x[artIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
}

var toughIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("toughSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  toughIndex++;
  if (toughIndex > x.length) {
    toughIndex = 1
  }
  x[toughIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 12000);
}

var epicIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("epicSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  epicIndex++;
  if (epicIndex > x.length) {
    epicIndex = 1
  }
  x[epicIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
}

var colorIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("colorSlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  colorIndex++;
  if (colorIndex > x.length) {
    colorIndex = 1
  }
  x[colorIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
}

var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides9");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
} <
/script></td >

<
td >

  <
  div class = "w3-content w3-section"
style = "max-width:700px" >
  <
  img class = "mySlides10 w3-animate-fading"
src = "hero1.jpg"
style = "width:100%"
alt = "" >
  <
  img class = "mySlides10 w3-animate-fading"
src = "hero2.jpg"
style = "width:100%"
alt = "" >
  <
  img class = "mySlides10 w3-animate-fading"
src = "hero3.jpg"
style = "width:100%"
alt = "" >
  <
  img class = "mySlides10 w3-animate-fading"
src = "hero4.jpg"
style = "width:100%"
alt = "" >
  <
  /div>

  <
  script >
  var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides10");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 9000);
}
```

```css
div.a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">


<center>
  <div align="center">

    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>

          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="coupleSlides w3-animate-fading" src="couple1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="coupleSlides w3-animate-fading" src="couple2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="coupleSlides w3-animate-fading" src="couple3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>


        </td>
        <td>

          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="animatedSlides w3-animate-fading" src="animated1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="animatedSlides w3-animate-fading" src="animated2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="animatedSlides w3-animate-fading" src="animated3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>
        </td>

        <td>

          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="coldSlides w3-animate-fading" src="cold1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="coldSlides w3-animate-fading" src="cold2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="coldSlides w3-animate-fading" src="cold3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="shockSlides w3-animate-fading" src="shock1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="shockSlides w3-animate-fading" src="shock2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="shockSlides w3-animate-fading" src="shock3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>
        </td>

        <td align="center" valign="bottom">
          <font face="Futura" size="5" color="#FFFFFF"><b>DVDizzy.com</b><br></font>
        </td>


        <td>
          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="art1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="art2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="art3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="art4.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="art5.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>

          <script>
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="tough1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="tough4.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="tough2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="tough3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="tough5.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>
        </td>

        <td align="center" valign="center">
          <font face="Futura" color="#FFFFFF">
            <font size="6"><b>#CenturyProject</b></font>

            <br><br><br>
            <font size="3"><i>Coming soon</i></font>
          </font>
        </td>


        <td>
          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="epicSlides w3-animate-fading" src="epic3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="epicSlides w3-animate-fading" src="epic1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="epicSlides w3-animate-fading" src="epic2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>
          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="colorSlides w3-animate-fading" src="colorful1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="colorSlides w3-animate-fading" src="colorful2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="colorSlides w3-animate-fading" src="colorful3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>

        </td>



        <td>

          <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
            <img class="mySlides9 w3-animate-fading" src="group1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="mySlides9 w3-animate-fading" src="group2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            <img class="mySlides9 w3-animate-fading" src="group3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
          </div>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be all carousel function and slide index variables are unique.

Check below snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>#CenturyProject - DVDizzy.com</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/w3.css">

<body bgcolor="#000000">

  <script>

    var myimages = new Array()
    function preloadimages() {
      for (i = 0; i < preloadimages.arguments.length; i++) {
        myimages[i] = new Image()
        myimages[i].src = preloadimages.arguments[i]
      }
    }

    preloadimages("https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/couple1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/couple2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/couple3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/animated1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/animated2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/animated3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/cold1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/cold2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/cold3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/shock1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/shock2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/shock3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art4.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art5.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/colorful1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/colorful2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/colorful3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/group1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/group2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/group3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/epic1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/epic2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/epic3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero4.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough1.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough2.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough3.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough4.jpg", "https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough5.jpg")

  </script>

  <center>
    <div align="center">
      div.a {
      text-align: center;
      }
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>

            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="coupleSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/couple1.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="coupleSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/couple2.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="coupleSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/couple3.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var coupleIndex = 0;
              carousel1();

              function carousel1() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("coupleSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                coupleIndex++;
                if (coupleIndex > x.length) { coupleIndex = 1 }
                x[coupleIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel1, 9000);
              }
            </script>

          </td>

          <td>

            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="animatedSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/animated1.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="animatedSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/animated2.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="animatedSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/animated3.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var animatedIndex = 0;
              carousel2();

              function carousel2() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("animatedSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                animatedIndex++;
                if (animatedIndex > x.length) { animatedIndex = 1 }
                x[animatedIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel2, 8500);
              }
            </script>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="coldSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/cold1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="coldSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/cold2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="coldSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/cold3.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var coldIndex = 0;
              carousel3();

              function carousel3() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("coldSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                coldIndex++;
                if (coldIndex > x.length) { coldIndex = 1 }
                x[coldIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel3, 7000);
              }
            </script>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="shockSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/shock1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="shockSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/shock2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="shockSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/shock3.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var shockIndex = 0;
              carousel4();

              function carousel4() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("shockSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                shockIndex++;
                if (shockIndex > x.length) { shockIndex = 1 }
                x[shockIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel4, 7500);
              }
            </script>
          </td>

          <td align="center" valign="bottom">
            <font face="Futura" size="5" color="#FFFFFF"><b>DVDizzy.com</b><br></font>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art3.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art4.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="artSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/art5.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var artIndex = 0;
              carousel5();

              function carousel5() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("artSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                artIndex++;
                if (artIndex > x.length) { artIndex = 1 }
                x[artIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel5, 9000);
              }
            </script>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough4.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough3.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="toughSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/tough5.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var toughIndex = 0;
              carousel6();

              function carousel6() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("toughSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                toughIndex++;
                if (toughIndex > x.length) { toughIndex = 1 }
                x[toughIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel6, 12000);
              }
            </script>
          </td>

          <td align="center" valign="center">
            <font face="Futura" color="#FFFFFF">
              <font size="6"><b>#CenturyProject</b></font>

              <br><br><br>
              <font size="3"><i>Coming soon</i></font>
            </font>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="epicSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/epic1.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="epicSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/epic2.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="epicSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/epic3.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var epicIndex = 0;
              carousel7();

              function carousel7() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("epicSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                epicIndex++;
                if (epicIndex > x.length) { epicIndex = 1 }
                x[epicIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel7, 7000);
              }
            </script>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="colorSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/colorful1.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="colorSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/colorful2.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
              <img class="colorSlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/colorful3.jpg"
                style="width:100%" alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var colorIndex = 0;
              carousel8();

              function carousel8() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("colorSlides");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                colorIndex++;
                if (colorIndex > x.length) { colorIndex = 1 }
                x[colorIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel8, 5000);
              }
            </script>

          </td>

          <td>

            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="groupslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/group1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="groupslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/group2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="groupslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/group3.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var groupIndex = 0;
              carousel9();

              function carousel9() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("groupslide");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                groupIndex++;
                if (groupIndex > x.length) { groupIndex = 1 }
                x[groupIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel9, 9000);
              }
            </script>
          </td>

          <td>

            <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:700px">
              <img class="heroslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero1.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="heroslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero2.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="heroslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero3.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
              <img class="heroslide w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.dvdizzy.com/cp/hero4.jpg" style="width:100%"
                alt="">
            </div>

            <script>
              var heroIndex = 0;
              carousel10();

              function carousel10() {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("heroslide");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                  x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                heroIndex++;
                if (heroIndex > x.length) { heroIndex = 1 }
                x[heroIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(carousel10, 9000);
              }
            </script>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Manish!